# dplyr crash when using lagged difference computation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame 4 million rows and 1.4 million distinct values of a grouping variable. Sample DF looks like this:

```
> df
        date        id
1 2015-06-25   4333864
2 2015-06-25   3867895
3 2015-06-25   4333866
4 2015-06-25   4333868
5 2015-06-29   2900522
6 2015-06-29   3609093
```

Using this command to do lagged date differences crashes R on an 8GB memory MAC:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(dayDiff = date - lag(date))
```

Is this dplyr being memory hungry? Any other efficient way to accomplish what I need?

Here is the version of *dplyr* I am using:

```
Package: dplyr
Type: Package
Version: 0.4.1
```

Date frame has the following variable types:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date: Date, format: "2014-07-01" "2014-07-01" "2014-07-01" ...
 $ id  : num  1793096 2019424 1869572 1869573 1774661 ...
```

Comment: Try changing the -> into a pipe operator

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo in my post. Nothing to do with the crash.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `str(df)`? (Add it to the question, not in comments please)

Comment: And what version of dplyr are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The following is an implementation of lag() that avoids grouping the df. It scales much better with many groups (although not sure 1.4M)

```html
lag_grouped_by = function(var, ...){
  # ... vars to group_by
  args <- list(...)
  
  tibble(!!!args, .name_repair = ~paste0("var", 1:length(args))) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
    mutate(var = var) %>% 
    arrange(across(-c(var,row))) %>%
    mutate(across(-c(var,row), ~replace_na(.x,"encode_NAs"))) %>%
    mutate(across(-c(var,row), ~.x==lag(.x))) %>% 
    mutate(cond = rowSums(across(-c(var,row))) == length(args)) %>% 
    mutate(lag_var = lag(var)) %>%
    arrange(row) %>%
    mutate(lag_var = if_else(cond, lag_var, NA, NA)) %>%
    pull(lag_var)
}
```

Instead of:

```html
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>% 
 mutate(dayDiff = date - lag(date))
```

Try:

```html
df %>%
 mutate(
  lag_date = lag_grouped_by(date, id),
  dayDiff = date - lag_date
 )
```

Comment: Absolutely scales! I had a go at this using `data.table`, and by returning integers using `dplyr`. On a sample dataset with 4m rows and 1.4m unique id values, my approaches took around 2.3 minutes. Your solution took 1.77 seconds. Very impressive. It would be great if you could provide further context explaining how your solution works so that others may benefit in the future. Thanks

Comment: And also, add the packages your function uses to your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear! Sure, the only dependency is `library(tidyverse)`, but that was implicit from the use of `mutate()`. The way it works is by arranging the rows so that same groups are placed together. Then I calculate a flag (the variable `cond`), which evaluates to `F` when some of the grouping variables are different than their lag (which means that it belongs to a different group). When the flag is `F`, we have NA, otherwise, the `lag()` of the variable. When the flag is NA, the output is NA (this is an assumption equivalent to specifying the `default` argument in the `lag()` function to `NA`.