# dplyr crashes when using window function on large data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a complex block of dplyr code that has worked successfully on a data frame containing 5,200,000 rows. Since I wrote the code I have updated my R version from 3.1.2 to 3.2.0, and currently using Revolution R Open (RRO) 3.2.0

Running the code block now on the same data causes RStudio to error with

```
fatal error - R Session Aborted
```

The error occurs both under RRO 3.2.0 and normal R 3.2.0

I am equally not sure if it is the window functions used (lag & row_number) that are the culprits. I am mostly interested in finding out what is causing the statement to crash R/RStudio, as opposed to rewriting the dplyr statement, but happy to receive tips on better dplyr practices :-)

I have looked at the following questions on Stackoverflow [dplyr crash when using lagged difference computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611958/dplyr-crash-when-using-lagged-difference-computation)
and 
[dplyr crashes when using summarise with segfault error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915551/dplyr-crashes-when-using-summarise-with-segfault-error)
but don't feel they relate to my query.

I can successfully run the dplyr statement on half the data using the slice operator, and is equally successful on the other half of the data, so I don't believe it is an issue with the data.

I have been able to replicate the error on a data frame with sample data.

This is the code to generate the sample data frame DF

```
library(dplyr)
# create an ID column with some containing duplicate values
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(ID = floor(runif(5200000, 1,3000000)))

# Order data frame by ID, YEAR
DF <- tbl_df(DF) %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(YEAR = row_number()) %>%
arrange(ID, YEAR)     

# create and event variable which is set to 0 80% of the time 1 10% etc.
DF$EVENT <- sample(0:5,5200000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.015, 0.01))

# create a vector of unique IDs
unique_IDs <- unique(DF$ID)
# take a 10% sample of the unique IDs
init_set <- sample(unique_IDs, replace = FALSE, size =  round(length(unique_IDs)*0.1) )
# create an index of the 10% sample IDs
init.idx <- DF$ID %in% init_set

# create an initialisation state variable with Y and N values
DF$INIT_STATE <- as.factor(ifelse(init.idx,"Y","N"))
```

The dplyr statement I am running looks as follows:

```
tbl_df(DF) %>%     
    select(ID, YEAR, EVENT, INIT_STATE) %>%
    # slice(1:2600000) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%                                                    # group by ID to control window functions
    arrange(ID, YEAR) %>%                                               # sort by ID, YEAR (just to be sure, may not be needed)
    mutate(event_lag = lag(EVENT)                                       # add attr which shifts the event number by a lag of 1 (YEAR_COUNTER is set to zero in the year after the event)
           , event_lag = ifelse(is.na(event_lag), 0, event_lag) ) %>%   # first lag in the ID group is NA, this sets it to 0
    mutate(i = cumsum(ifelse(event_lag, 1, 0))) %>%                     # create cumulative count of lagged number of events (used for grouping)
    group_by(i, add = TRUE) %>%                                         # now add another clause to the group by 
    mutate(row_rank = row_number()                                      # row_number is a counter that restarts in every group (ID and i)
           , year_ini = ifelse(i == 0 & INIT_STATE == "N", 5, 0)        # add attribute that determines if the EVENT_COUNTER starts at 5 yrs or 0 yrs
           , YEAR_COUNTER = year_ini + row_rank - 1) %>%                # the EVENT_COUNTER is now the sum between the EVENT initialisation + the row counter. -1 starts counter from 0
    select(-(event_lag:year_ini))
```

I have added comments against each line in the dplyr statement to indicate what is intended with each step.

A successful run on half the data looks as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [2,600,000 x 6]
Groups: ID, i

   i ID YEAR EVENT INIT_STATE YEAR_COUNTER
1  0  1    1     1          N            5
2  1  1    2     0          N            0
3  1  1    3     0          N            1
4  1  1    4     0          N            2
5  1  1    5     0          N            3
6  0  2    1     0          N            5
7  0  3    1     0          N            5
8  0  3    2     0          N            6
9  0  3    3     2          N            7
10 0  4    1     0          N            5
.. . ..  ...   ...        ...          ...
```

In addition to the session info below, I have 192Gb RAM on the server, and I don't see any significant spikes in the memory usage while the dplyr statement runs.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5    assertthat_0.1  parallel_3.2.0  DBI_0.3.1       tools_3.2.0     Rcpp_0.11.6
```

Comment: I have just update to RRO 3.2.1 and dplyr 0.4.2 and this appears to have solved the problem, which is great news.

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated to RRO 3.2.1 and dplyr 0.4.2 and this appears to have solved the problem, which is great news. Thanks to anyone who looked at the question.